# automatic creation and solution (in symbolic form) of a system of equations in python

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

tell me , how to solve the following problem: I need to solve a system of nonlinear equations in python (scipy, sympy, or using some other library). The problem is not in the ability to solve a system of equations in python, but in the fact that the number of equations is a solution (N) to another problem and is not known in advance. It is not difficult for me to automatically generate a system from k-equations (for example, I previously asked the question [solution system of linear equations in sympy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66911929/solution-system-of-linear-equations-in-sympy), but I was not given an answer ).

I rewrote the code in the above link in the form (the system of equations is written manually) :

scipy-variant :

```
 def soleq(n):
     def equations(p):
         if n==4:
             x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,z1,z2,z3,z4= p
             a1=1 ### 1/kT1
             a2=2 ### 1/kT2
             a3=3 ### 1/kT3
             a4=4 ### 1/kT4
             a5=5 ### 1/kT5
             a6=6 ### 1/kT6
             a7=7 ### 1/kT7
             a8=8 ### 1/kT8
             a9=9 ### 1/kT9
             a10=10 ### 1/kT10
             a11=11 ### 1/kT11
             a12=12 ### 1/kT12
             mui1_exp=1 
             mui2_exp=2
             mui3_exp=3
             mui4_exp=4
             mui5_exp=5
             mui6_exp=6
             mui7_exp=7
             mui8_exp=8
             mui9_exp=9
             mui10_exp=10
             mui11_exp=11
             mui12_exp=12
             eq1=(a1*x1-y1)*z1+(a1*x2-y2)*z2+(a1*x3-y3)*z3+(a1*x4-y4)*z4-mui1_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4)
             eq2=(a2*x1-y1)*z1+(a2*x2-y2)*z2+(a2*x3-y3)*z3+(a2*x4-y4)*z4-mui2_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4)
             eq3=(a3*x1-y1)*z1+(a3*x2-y2)*z2+(a3*x3-y3)*z3+(a3*x4-y4)*z4-mui3_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4)
             eq4=(a4*x1-y1)*z1+(a4*x2-y2)*z2+(a4*x3-y3)*z3+(a4*x4-y4)*z4-mui4_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4)
             eq5=(a5*x1-y1)*z1+(a5*x2-y2)*z2+(a5*x3-y3)*z3+(a5*x4-y4)*z4-mui5_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4)
             eq6=(a6*x1-y1)*z1+(a6*x2-y2)*z2+(a6*x3-y3)*z3+(a6*x4-y4)*z4-mui6_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4)
             eq7=(a7*x1-y1)*z1+(a7*x2-y2)*z2+(a7*x3-y3)*z3+(a7*x4-y4)*z4-mui7_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4)
             eq8=(a8*x1-y1)*z1+(a8*x2-y2)*z2+(a8*x3-y3)*z3+(a8*x4-y4)*z4-mui8_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4)
             eq9=(a9*x1-y1)*z1+(a9*x2-y2)*z2+(a9*x3-y3)*z3+(a9*x4-y4)*z4-mui9_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4)
             eq10=(a10*x1-y1)*z1+(a10*x2-y2)*z2+(a10*x3-y3)*z3+(a10*x4-y4)*z4-mui10_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4)
             eq11=(a11*x1-y1)*z1+(a11*x2-y2)*z2+(a11*x3-y3)*z3+(a11*x4-y4)*z4-mui11_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4)
             eq12=(a12*x1-y1)*z1+(a12*x2-y2)*z2+(a12*x3-y3)*z3+(a12*x4-y4)*z4-mui12_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4)
         return (eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,eq7,eq8,eq9,eq10,eq11,eq12)
     x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,z1,z2,z3,z4 = fsolve(equations, (1, 1,1, 1,1, 1,1, 1,1, 1,1, 1))
     sol=equations((x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,z1,z2,z3,z4))
     print(np.abs(sol))
     return np.nan
 n=4
 a=soleq(n)
```

the presented scipi-option is working, but it is inconvenient to work with this option, because the construction "if n == 4: ...." will have to be prescribed many times, N can be 10 or 50 (it is not known in advance).
the variables to find are x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,z1,z2,z3,z4 and these variables can be N

here is the same version of the equations, only in sympy :

```
 eq1=sp.Eq((a1*x1-y1)*z1+(a1*x2-y2)*z2+(a1*x3-y3)*z3+(a1*x4-y4)*z4-mui1_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4))
 eq2=sp.Eq((a2*x1-y1)*z1+(a2*x2-y2)*z2+(a2*x3-y3)*z3+(a2*x4-y4)*z4-mui2_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4))
 eq3=sp.Eq((a3*x1-y1)*z1+(a3*x2-y2)*z2+(a3*x3-y3)*z3+(a3*x4-y4)*z4-mui3_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4))
 eq4=sp.Eq((a4*x1-y1)*z1+(a4*x2-y2)*z2+(a4*x3-y3)*z3+(a4*x4-y4)*z4-mui4_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4))
 eq5=sp.Eq((a5*x1-y1)*z1+(a5*x2-y2)*z2+(a5*x3-y3)*z3+(a5*x4-y4)*z4-mui5_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4))
 eq6=sp.Eq((a6*x1-y1)*z1+(a6*x2-y2)*z2+(a6*x3-y3)*z3+(a6*x4-y4)*z4-mui6_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4))
 eq7=sp.Eq((a7*x1-y1)*z1+(a7*x2-y2)*z2+(a7*x3-y3)*z3+(a7*x4-y4)*z4-mui7_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4))
 eq8=sp.Eq((a8*x1-y1)*z1+(a8*x2-y2)*z2+(a8*x3-y3)*z3+(a8*x4-y4)*z4-mui8_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4))
 eq9=sp.Eq((a9*x1-y1)*z1+(a9*x2-y2)*z2+(a9*x3-y3)*z3+(a9*x4-y4)*z4-mui9_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4))
 eq10=sp.Eq((a10*x1-y1)*z1+(a10*x2-y2)*z2+(a10*x3-y3)*z3+(a10*x4-y4)*z4-mui10_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4))
 eq11=sp.Eq((a11*x1-y1)*z1+(a11*x2-y2)*z2+(a11*x3-y3)*z3+(a11*x4-y4)*z4-mui11_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4))
 eq12=sp.Eq((a12*x1-y1)*z1+(a12*x2-y2)*z2+(a12*x3-y3)*z3+(a12*x4-y4)*z4-mui12_exp*(z1+z2+z3+z4))
```

solver options that I tried to use to solve, for example, such a system :
sol = sp.solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,eq7,eq8,eq9,eq10,eq11,eq12])
sol = solve(equ, x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,z1,z2,z3,z4,dict=True, manual=True, check=False)
sol = nonlinsolve(equ,x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,z1,z2,z3,z4)
equ=(eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,eq7,eq8,eq9,eq10,eq11,eq12)
sol = sp.solve(equ,x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,z1,z2,z3,z4, rational=False)
sol = sp.solve((eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5,eq6,eq7,eq8,eq9,eq10,eq11,eq12)
(x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,z1,z2,z3,z4))

the code is launched with these sympy-solvers, but it is impossible to wait for a solution and errors do not come out; sympy, in principle, suits me, but how to make him solve such systems ???
In both examples, the variables to find are x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,y3,y4,z1,z2,z3,z4 and these variables can be N .
in other words, I need an algorithm to automatically create and solve (symbolically) a system of equations

Answer (score 0):

The code you have given does not work as you intend because you try to solve `equations` but that is a function that defines the equations. To generate the equations you need to pass to it the variables to use as `p` like `equations(symbols('x1:%s,y1:%s,z1:%s'%tuple([n+1]*3)))`. So the call would look like `fsolve(equations(symbols('x1:%s,y1:%s,z1:%s'%tuple([n+1]*3))), (1,)*12)` for an initial guess of all 1s.

Here is how I would generate your system of equations based on the example you gave for n=4:

```
from sympy.abc import *
from sympy import *

def neq(n): 
    x=symbols('x1:' + str(n+1))
    y=symbols('y1:' + str(n+1))
    z=symbols('z1:' + str(n+1))
    a = symbols('a1:%s' % (3*n+1)) 
    muiexp = symbols('muiexp1:%s' % (3*n+1))
    v = x+y+z 
    ysum = sum(z) 
    eq = []
    for i in range(3*n): 
        terms = [] 
        for j in range(n): 
            terms.append((a[i]*x[j]-y[j])*z[j]) 
        eq.append(Add(*terms) - muiexp[i]*ysum) 
    return eq,v

>>> e, v = neq(2)
>>> for i in e: print(i)
-muiexp1*(z1 + z2) + z1*(a1*x1 - y1) + z2*(a1*x2 - y2)
-muiexp2*(z1 + z2) + z1*(a2*x1 - y1) + z2*(a2*x2 - y2)
-muiexp3*(z1 + z2) + z1*(a3*x1 - y1) + z2*(a3*x2 - y2)
-muiexp4*(z1 + z2) + z1*(a4*x1 - y1) + z2*(a4*x2 - y2)
-muiexp5*(z1 + z2) + z1*(a5*x1 - y1) + z2*(a5*x2 - y2)
-muiexp6*(z1 + z2) + z1*(a6*x1 - y1) + z2*(a6*x2 - y2)

>>> solve(*neq(2))
[(x2, x2, y2, y2, -z2, z2)]
>>> solve(*neq(4))
[((x2*z2 + x3*z3 + x4*z4)/(z2 + z3 + z4), x2, x3, x4, (y2*z2 + y3*z3 + y4*z4)/(z2 + z3 + z4), y2, y3, y4, -z2 - z3 - z4, z2, z3, z4)]
```

Let's look at the simplest system when n = 1:

```
>>> e, v = neq(1)
>>> for i in e:i
... 
-muiexp1*z1 + z1*(a1*x1 - y1)
-muiexp2*z1 + z1*(a2*x1 - y1)
-muiexp3*z1 + z1*(a3*x1 - y1)

>>> from sympy import nonlinsolve
>>> nonlinsolve(e, v)
FiniteSet((x1, y1, 0))
```

This is one trivial solution because z1 factors out of each equation. So if it is 0 it doesn't matter what x1 and y1 are. Is there a non-trivial solution? solve the first equation for x1 and substitute into the second, then solve the second for y1 and substitute into the 3rd. Solve for z1 and you find that it is 0. There is no non-trivial solution.

```
>>> solve(e[0],x1)
[(muiexp1 + y1)/a1]
>>> _x1=_[0];solve(e[1].subs(x1,_x1),y1)
[(-a1*muiexp2 + a2*muiexp1)/(a1 - a2)]
>>> _y1=_[0];solve(e[2].subs(x1,_x1).subs(y1,_y1),z1)
[0]
>>> Tuple(*e).subs(z1,0)
(0, 0, 0)
```

When n=2 the case is similar:

```
>>> solve(*neq(2))
[(x2, x2, y2, y2, -z2, z2)]
```

The solution indicates that when z1 and z2 have opposite sign (or are both 0), the only solution is when x1 = x2 and y1 = y2.

If you don't think the solver is telling you the truth, it only takes one counter example: find a solution that doesn't match the pattern described and then there is an issue with SymPy's solver. If not, then it is a problem with our understanding.

The power of the symbolic system, however, it that it can be used to demonstrate the truth of the general solution.

```
e, v = neq(4)
sol = nonlinsolve(e, v)
gen = list(sol)[0]  # there is only one general solution
reps = dict(zip(v, gen))
[i.xreplace(reps).factor() for i in e]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

So the general solution is correct. You can look at any number of specific solutions. Here is one:

```
from random import random
from symyp import Rationa, Tuple
arb = {i: Rational(str(round(random(),2))) for i,j in zip(v, gen) if i == j}
for i,j in zip(v, gen):
    arb[i] = j.xreplace(arb)
print(arb)
print(Tuple(*eq).xreplace(arb))
```

which happened to be

```
{x2: 89/100, x3: 73/100, x4: 6/25, y2: 83/100, y3: 3/20, y4: 13/50, z2: 
1/100, z3: 11/25, z4: 3/5, x1: 4741/10500, y1: 329/1500, z1: -21/20}
(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: thanks for your attention, I have corrected your code - run it and see

Comment: I will write the corrected code piece by piece, because I don’t know how to add all the code ( part code № 1 )
def neq(n):
    x=symbols('x:' + str(n+1))
    y=symbols('y:' + str(n+1))
    z=symbols('z:' + str(n+1))
    a = symbols('a:%s' % ((n+1)*3))
    muiexp = symbols('muiexp:%s' % ((n+1)*3))
    v = x+y+z
    ysum = sum(z)
    for i in range((n+1)*3):
        terms = []
        for j in range(n+1):
            terms.append((a[i]*x[j]-y[j])*z[j])
            eq.append(Add(*terms) - muiexp[i]*ysum)
    i=0
    equations=[]
        i=0
    equations=[]

Comment: part code №2:
for i in range((n+1)*3):
        terms = []
        for j in range(n+1):
            terms.append((a[i]*x[j]-y[j])*z[j])
            eq.append(Add(*terms) - muiexp[i]*ysum)

Comment: part code №3 : 
    i=0
    equations=[]
    while i<(len(eq)-3):
        equations.append(eq[i+3])
        i=i+3
        i+=1
    return equations,v

Comment: part code № 4:
e, v = neq(3)

print('')
print('')
print('e', e)
print('')
print('')
print('v', v)
print('')
print('')
print('new N',len(e))
print('')
print('')
sol=solve(e,v)
print('sol',sol)

Comment: if you run the code, you will see that you need to solve the system of equations written in a variable "equations" and when the result is output "solve(e,v)" , then it is clear that, in fact, python (sympy) does not solve the system of equations

Comment: See the updated answer and note that the `symbols` are created starting from 1 (and that is where there was an extra one added to the value `n + 1`, `3*n + 1`. I would recommend that you check your equations that are generated by hand for n=1, then n=2...then you will know that your `neq` routine is working as you expect.

Comment: what produces "solve" is not an answer, the result "solve" should be expressions for variables x,y,z

Comment: The solution indicates that there are infinite solutions; any variable that is reported as itself as a solution means you can pick any value for it. The non-self solutions are the specific value for the given arbitrary values. Take the solution for n == 2: pick values for x1, y2 and z2 and then x1=x2, y1= y2, z1 = -z2 are a solution.

Comment: sorry that such an answer, but I think simpi simply does not solve the system

Comment: See the addition to the answer and follow Sherlock's dictum: 'Once you eliminate the impossible, whatever remains, no matter how improbable, must be the truth.' There may be other possibilities, too, like the set of equations I am showing is not the set of equations you intend to be solving.

Comment: Good day . I saw your answer yesterday, but there was no way to answer. The fact is that the system of equations, as presented in my previous messages, will always be the same (in structure), the number of equations will be new each time. The question is how to train simpi or scipi to get a unique and real solution (or expression) for each variable?

Comment: Take the case of n=1. There is not a *unique* solution. There are infinite solutions, e.g. (1, 2, 0), (pi, e, 0), etc... If you don't believe this is so then check your equations. There are 3 equations and 3 unknowns in that case. So if the equations are right then that is the answer: there is no unique answer.

Comment: if there are N variables, then there will be N equations and there must be a unique solution. In my opinion, sympy, does not know how to solve systems of equations in symbolic form from N equations

Comment: Please demonstrate by showing that there is a unique solution for the case of n=1.

Comment: N strictly > = 3 and it cannot be less. I need simpi in symbolic form to solve a similar system of equations for any N

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer. I don't think I can add anything more to the discussion. The equation set defined above has infinite solutions. The solver tells you that and you can confirm that it is correct. You can also pick an arbitrary specific solution. If this is not how you think the equation set should behave, then we are talking about the wrong equation set. Sometimes general sets of equations need a "conservation condition", a constraint instead of the patterned equation, that tells how the unknowns alone must behave (like all sum to 1 or something like that).

Comment: that is, you want to say that if you program a system of equations in a symbolic form, then it is impossible to get a unique and real solution in simpi? What other python library is there that can solve a system of equations in symbolic form?

Comment: The equation `x - 1` as a single solution and `solve(x - 1) -> [1]`; your system of equations does not have a unique solution, it has infinite solutions and SymPy cannot tell you otherwise.